# How can i see http requests sent from client to Jersey Web service

Tags: http, ssl, jersey

As the title explains, I want to see the http requests that are sent by my android app client to my Jersey Web service.

Also, I'm using
https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request
class for sending the requests, but I'm not sure if they are SSL encrypted. Can I see if they are encrypted by looking at the http requests that arrive at my Web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the server on which your web service is running, you can use Wireshark : https://www.wireshark.org/

This will trace and decode the tcp/ip protocol for you, and indeed show you if it's encrypted under SSL.

Assuming you own the server, and have full access, you can also install the Private Key from your server into Wireshark, and it will then show you decoded SSL traffic.

Comment: Currently, the server is on my computer (tomcat) so what do I need to do in this case?

Comment: Access the URL above, download and install the version of Wireshark for your operating system and start it up. You will see a list of network adapters on your computer, select the one you are using, and start capturing.